How to build a type-safe factory function in TypeScript?
I want to create a object use a json object like
const data = {type :'A', param: [1,2]}

so I can call
const i:A = create(data)

I wish compiler can check whether the type string and param array be matched
what I already got is like:
const Ctors = {
    A: class {
        constructor(a: number, b: number) { }
    },
    B: class {
        constructor(s: string) { }
    }
};

type keys = keyof typeof Ctors;
function create<K extends keys>(k: K, ...p: ConstructorParameters<typeof Ctors[K]>) {
    return new Ctors[k](...p);
}

create('A', 1, 2);
create('B', 's')

the only problem is I had to modify
return new Ctors[k](...p); to return new (Ctors[k] as any)(...p);
or there will be an error:
A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.ts(2556)
I can live with an 'as any' but it seems not make sense, I want to know why and if there is a way to avoid it

If you really care about this you need to use the technique described in ms/TS#47109 involving mapped types and generic indexed accesses. See this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?
